# Designing an object hierarchy where objects can parse themselves

Tags: java, parsing

I am designing a simulator with a hierarchy of simulated objects. To bootstrap the simulator, the initial objects must be loaded from a file. Each object will have to parse itself from a simple key-value textual representation. We will want to add new object classes from time to time.

Unfortunately, there is no "static inheritance" in Java. In particular, the following approach would have been nice to have:

```
public class SimObject {
   /**
    * (unfortunately illegal) - to be implemented by subclasses,
    * returns a new object if successful, or none on failure.
    */
   static abstract SimObject buildFromAttributes(Map<String,String> attrs);

  // ... other constructors, behavior
}
```

This would have allowed the use of something like the following parsing code, which creates a `SimObject` of the appropriate type by looking up the first parser that build it correctly:

```
public SimObject parse(Map<String,String> attrs, Class<SimObject>[] classes) {
   for (Class<SimObject> c : classes) {
       SimObject o = c.buildFromAttributes(attrs); // illegal, I know
       if (o != null) return o;
   } 
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not create valid simobject");
}
```

Since that is not possible, I am currently using

```
public class SimObject {
   /** empty constructor, to call buildFromAttributes from */
   SimObject() {} 
   /**
    * returns a new object if successful, or none on failure.
    */
   abstract SimObject buildFromAttributes(Map<String,String> attrs);

  // ... other constructors, behavior
}
```

and

```
public SimObject parse(Map<String,String> attrs, SimObject[] instances) {
   for (SimObject i : instances) {
       SimObject o = i.buildFromAttributes(attrs);
       if (o != null) return o;
   } 
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not create valid simobject");
}
```

Which works, but it seems ugly to have a `buildFromAttributes` that should have been `static`, in the sense that it does not access or modify the state of its object.

Another option would be to use separate objects to do the parsing (call them `SimObjectBuilder`s, and have one of those per `SimObject` subclass); but those objects would be very coupled to the internal implementation of the objects that they build, and I would like to keep the code as short and clear as possible.

Additional requirements: I would like to avoid using a `"class"` attribute to implement reflection-based parsing (which would remove the need for iterating through possible parsers by zeroing in directly on the good one); or external libraries. This is an exercise in design for use with students learning OO where the focus is simplicity and clarity, not production code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your requirements as I see it:

1) Dont want to define any new `SimObjectBuilders` like types.

2) Dont want to create SimObject objects just to parse them.

3) No reflection.

Then you can use lambdas and build in `Function` type by wrapping it with static methods defined in each subclass of SimObject:

```
    SimObject o = parse( new HashMap<>(), Arrays.asList(
    SimObject1::buildFromAttributes, SimObject2::buildFromAttributes ) );

    public SimObject parse(Map<String,String> attrs, 
    List< Function<Map<String,String>, SimObject> > factories) {
        for (Function<Map<String,String>, SimObject> f : factories) {
            SimObject o = f.apply(attrs);
            if (o != null) return o;
        } 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not create valid simobject");
     }
```

And here are your subclasses:

```
public class SimObject1 extends SimObject{

    public static SimObject1 buildFromAttributes(Map<String,String> attrs){
        return new SimObject1();
    }
}

public class SimObject2 extends SimObject{

    public static SimObject2 buildFromAttributes(Map<String,String> attrs){
        return new SimObject2();
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice, and much lighter weight than building a SimBuilderFactory hierarchy echoing the actual SimObject hierarchy.

Comment: This solution is interesting according to OP requirements. You have my vote. But it is often an anti pattern to put all the business logic in static methods.

Comment: @davidxxx. There are a lot of examples in Java API itself where factory methods are static. I personally don't see a problem with usage of static methods in this way. Also if we need to change how we create the subclasses we can either change the method itself or create a different one and pass into `factories`list.

Comment: Static factory methods of Java API are not application/business code, these are stable and base structures. In the very most of cases, you don't need to mock them or to switch to other factory classes. "Also if we need to change how we create the subclasses we can either change the method itself or create a different one and pass into factorieslist." Sure. But if you want to mock them in a unit test or switch to other class implementations in a testing environment ? How to do ? These are hard coded and strongly coupled to class dependencies.

Comment: @davidxxx. For mocking you can use PowerMock. As for switching factories you can always reference them via `Function` interface as it is done in this example.

Comment: 1) Switching implementation doesn't mean changing all the invocations. It is not a robust way. It means switching to other subclass in a transparent way. For example, dependency injection helps for it but relies on instance and not class. 2) To mock, PowerMock relies on reflection and hides often design issue. If you consider that valid for testing, why not use it in the implementation ?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a design exercise, segregating object creation from its behavior would be a superior design.

You can create a hierarchy of Factory objects parallel to the simulation object hierarchy, which would then allow you to use code similar to what you have now (replacing the SimObject array with SimObjectFactory).

Besides the clarity that comes from stricter separation of parsing code and behavioral code, you can also implement several factories for the same object type, supporting several input formats.

Comment: Choosing what concerns to separate is also part of the design process. I agree that in general those two can be separated; but in this particular case, I would rather do it as tsolakp suggests, avoiding builder proliferation, and keeping closely coupled classes together.

Comment: Tsolakp's answer is the same as mine with the exception that he uses `Function` as his builder interface (breaking the semantics of function imo). If keeping coupled classes together is a concern, you can also define each builder as a nested class(although I’d prefer using the `default` access modifier to avoid unbridled access to an object’s internal structure).

Answer (score 1):

The actual way you would like to use defeats the OOP principles :

```
public SimObject parse(Map<String,String> attrs, Class<SimObject>[] classes) {
   for (Class<SimObject> c : classes) {
       SimObject o = c.buildFromAttributes(attrs); // illegal, I know
       if (o != null) return o;
   } 
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not create valid simobject");
}
```

Static methods are not designed to provide polymorphism behavior and `static` methods are strongly coupled with the class that declares them.
So it is harder to switch to another implementation, to use dependency injection mechanism or to mock the method in a straight way.

About the other options, I summarize :

- you don't want to use instance methods because you don't want to create "fake" objects.
- You don't want to separate the responsibilities : `SimObject` building and `SimObject` subclasses either.
- You don't want to use the reflection either.

Each Language has its limitations.
You seem to know those of the Java language.

> This is an exercise in design for use with students learning OO where
>   the focus is simplicity and clarity, not production code.

The way that separates `SimObject` building and `SimObject` subclasses is fine and rely on OOP principles :

- separating responsibilities
- factory pattern
- object collaborations
- maintainability of the code :  removing or adding a couple of `SimObject-SimObjectBuilder` is easy
- overriding

And even if you didn't specify that the question was for student OOP exercises, it is the way that I would propose.

> but those objects would be very coupled to the internal implementation
>   of the objects that they build  and I would like to keep the code as short and clear as possible.

The coupling is a one-way coupling : from the builder to the object to create.
It is fine and  it also seems expected that a builder that build instances of a specific class be coupled to this specific class.
So yes, clean code has a cost to write but also bring advantages to have a robust code that may more easily change.

Comment: The formatting of your answer really throws me off: lots of short sentences. Regarding the contents, I mostly agree; but I currently favor tsolakp's answer, as capturing the small-and-simple requirement better.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Interesting answer. I had though of this idea too. But I have some difficulties to write business code in static methods. It prevents from defining the builder subclass as dependencies in the client classes. So hard to switch to another implementation or to mock it in unit testing or mocked environment.